# Copy-Past in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I have looked at the code for copy-paste in VBA. When you do `.PasteSpecial` is there any difference between `Paste:=` or `()` (just using parentheses); e.g.:

`Worksheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste=:xlPasteValues`

or

`Worksheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)`

is this in any way different?

Comment: I don't think I understand your query but the difference in the 2 statements is that: your post **or** statement copies data to a range without posting anything in clipboard. Your pre **or** statement copies the data from clipboard with requirements you specify

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are ***Different***

the complete function is

```
PasteSpecial([Paste As XlPasteType = xlPasteAll], [Operation As XlPasteSpecialOperation = xlPasteSpecialOperationNone], [SkipBlanks], [Transpose])
```

you can notice that all arguments are ***Optional***
so `.PasteSpecial Paste=:xlPasteValues` means `Set arg Paste to xlPasteValues`

and also 
 `.PasteSpecial SkipBlanks:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues` means `Set arg SkipBlanks to True and Set arg Paste to xlPasteValues`

 ***But*** 
`.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` means `Set FIRST arg to xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 0):

### A Copy/Paste (PasteSpecial) Investigation

- Put some data into range `A1:A10` and out-comment the parts of the
  code you currently don't need to see the differences.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub PSpecInv()

    Const wsID As Variant = 1 ' e.g. "Sheet1" or 1 or...
    Const srcAddress As String = "A1:A10"
    Const tgtAddress As String = "B1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsID)
    Dim src As Range: Set src = ws.Range(srcAddress)
    Dim tgt As Range: Set tgt = ws.Range(tgtAddress)
    
' Copy/Paste

    ' Equivalents of a 'normal' copy/paste
    'The 'Selection' stays the same, 'CutCopyMode' is set to 'False'.
    src.Copy tgt
    src.Copy Destination:=tgt

' Copy/PasteSpecial

    ' After each of the following three code blocks, the 'Selection'
    ' on the worksheet becomes the Target Range ('B1:B10') and
    ' the 'CutCopyMode' gets set to 'True'.
    ' Equivalents of a 'PasteValues' copy/paste
    src.Copy
    tgt.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    tgt.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ' I don't know why the following line even works!
    tgt.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) ' works only if first argument (solo).
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Copy/PasteSpecial: Two Ways

    ' You have to know the order of the arguments:
    src.Copy
    tgt.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , True
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' You don't care about the order of the arguments:
    src.Copy
    tgt.PasteSpecial SkipBlanks:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
' The 'Assign' method (preferred)

    'The 'Selection' stays the same, 'CutCopyMode' stays the same.
    tgt.Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count).Value = src.Value

End Sub
```